# Could not able to install SQLite.Interop.dll in .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 windows application

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, sqlite-net

1. I have created the Desktop application with **.NET Framework, Version=v4.6.1**.
2. I have SQLite database.
3. I can able to communicate with the database in the development environment.
4. When I have created the setup file, everything is working as expected expect communication with SQLite database.
   The error while communicates with SQLite DB is:

[image: Error image 1]

5. So i got the google and found some solution as I have to add

   *Install-Package SQLite.Interop.dll -Version 1.0.103*
6. This also gives an error as below:

[image: Error image 2]

Please anyone help me out to here

Comment: How did you create the setup file? Which installer maker are you using? Does it have all the files in the Bin folder (or any changed path)? If you check the installed application in program files (default path), do you see all needed DLLs or just the application EXE and some but not SQLite?

Comment: I am not understanding why you have tried to install the `SQLite.Interop.dll` package? It is not needed for SQLite to work. An the error is pretty clear that the .Net framework installed in not compatible with that dll. Do you need to install the `SQLite.Interop.dll`?

Comment: I just see you tagged *sqlite-net*... Using the nuget `sqlite-net-pcl` (currently 1.7.335) install all that is needed and all is fine. Not compatible with EntityFramework because being a replacement as it is a light, very simple and efficient Code-First ORM that can be used with BindingListView. Or is it a mistake?

Comment: @JohnG Yes, I understood your point .Net framework installed in not compatible with that dll., Actually I have been installing that dll because error in first image says that dll could not be found, that's all
Please can you suggest me the solution for the Issue in First Image

Comment: @OlivierRogier I have followed the 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/how-to-create-a-setup-of-windows-application-in-net/

Comment: [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) | [InnoDependencyInstaller](https://github.com/DomGries/InnoDependencyInstaller) | [ISTool (inactive)](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Setup-creators/ISTool.shtml) | [Inno Script Studio](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio/) | [VS Setup Installer Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) | [Four Great Tools to Create Windows Installer Packages](https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/4-tools-to-create-windows-installer-packages/)